# Windows 7/8/Ubuntu 16.10 Triple Boot Issue

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7, windows-8, bios

Okay, so my issue with this is the fact that whenever the initial grub screen boots, I am able to see my Ubuntu boot option, and I can see Windows 8.1, but I cannot see Windows 7.

The only way I can boot into Windows 7 is to select to boot into Windows 8, then use the boot screen from there to boot into Windows 7. I want to know if there is a way to get Windows 7 to be able to boot from the grub screen.

Another thing that might throw a wrench in this: I am trying to do this on an old machine, so it does not have a UEFI interface.